# could not load file or assembly .NET

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

I have created a ASP.NET MVC 4 project and included Splicer to render images into a slideshow but when running the application I get the following error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Splicer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a66524ed949429f4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Any help ?

Comment: do you have any messages related to this exception in your ErrorList?

Comment: Are you using `Nuget` or have you simply downloaded the assembly from the Internet manually ?

Comment: this is downloaded manually.

Comment: Check the properties of the reference, check if "Specific Version" is True, if it is try toggling it to False.

Comment: I have added the files to the App-Data and then added the references.

Comment: The Specific Version is set to false - but didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the following cleansing operations:

1. Detect the location of the `Splicer.dll` file
2. Copy it to a safe location, which won't be deleted by accident and which resides somewhere within your solution so that while copying everything onto some other dev machine you won't have any surprises (using Windows Explorer, Visual Studio doesn't have to know about this action)
3. In Visual Studio, go to each and every project within your solution
4. For each project, expand the **References** folder and if you see a reference to `Splicer.dll` delete it, and add it again by browsing to the location you chose in step 2
5. Clean and rebuild your entire solution
6. Try again